# Oracle SQL Where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query:

```
select * from students stud
where stud.grade <= :grd
```

For example, I entered 80 in :grd, this displays all students that has a grade of 80 and below.

What I wanted is to display all the students if I entered nothing in :grd.

Is there a way to do this? Thanks :)

Comment: try this `select * from students where stud.grade < coalesce(:grd, stud.grade)  or  stud.grade = coalesce(:grd, stud.grade)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `coalesce` as below

```
select * from students 
where stud.grade <= coalesce(:grd,stud.grade);
```

Or use  `case when` as below:

```
select * from students 
where stud.grade <= 
case when :grd is null 
     then stud.grade 
     else :grd end;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Sir, does it have any difference from NVL(:grd,stud.grade)?

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for this! :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming column `stud.grade` cannot be more than 100 and given that you are using Oracle...

```
select *
from   students
where  stud.grade <= nvl(:grd, 100)
```

Comment: This is not my exact query sir. May I put stud.grade instead of 100 in NVL?

Comment: Try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

this query is enough to get what you want.

```
select * from students where stud.grade < coalesce(:grd, stud.grade) or stud.grade = coalesce(:grd, stud.grade)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
select * from students 
where (
        CASE 
        WHEN :grd  IS NULL THEN 1
        WHEN clct.contractid = :grd THEN 1
        ELSE 0 END = 1
        )
```